# Is it possible to add screen shots in the question?

Tags: support

Is it possible to add screen shots in the question. If yes **How**

Comment: You mean like this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/196352

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks for the answer(more like a comment)

Comment: Guessing that you know how to upload 2MB photo to your answer. Which mobile you are using? Take the screenshot--> Save the file-->adjust the image--> resize the image below 2mb size--> add picture to your answer body.